# New message pop up window on background c#

Tags: c#, .net, messagebox

I need a pop up window that will be displayed on the bottom right side of the screen.
It's supposed to pop when a new message is received within my software.
How can i program it? Create new form and use it? How can I program it to run on background without interrupting other user actions?

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend to look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx) on Codeproject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [`NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.showballoontip.aspx).  And [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160065.aspx) an example.

Basically, you add a [`NotifiyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) to your form, and do something like this (from the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160065.aspx) linked above):

```
void Form1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(20000, "Information", "This is the text",
        ToolTipIcon.Info );
}
```

Comment: i tried:                                                               private void notify_ballon()
        {
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000000, "you have new messeage", "blablalba", ToolTipIcon.Info);
        }                                                                  and ivoked the mathod, but nothing happens. debug shows the lines are acting., but still nothing is shown...

Comment: Hmm, without your actual code, I'm not sure I can help.  One possible thing: the NotifyIcon MSDN page says that the OS usually limits the max timeout to 30 seconds - yours is set to 1000.  You might reduce that a little.  Otherwise check out the NotifyIcon page to see if there might be any other suggestions.  See "Remarks" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160065.aspx and the entire example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) class and its method `ShowBalloonTip(Int32, String, String, ToolTipIcon)`